# Can't create new Vue inctance inside the script tag. Laravel 5.8

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

I am building a Laravel 5.8 app and i am using vue.js. 
My problem is that while i have the vue instance globaly like this on the app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

When I create new `Vue` instance inside the html script tag it says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

on the console.

```
`@section('scripts')
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app'.
        data: {}       
    })
</script>       
@endsection`
```

Comment: Are you loading the Vue library — and/or `app.js` — at the _end_ of the `<body>`?

Comment: yes i am linking it in the end before the </body>

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    @yield('scripts')
</body>

Comment: Charkoulis/Laravel github repository for all code.

Comment: Maybe the defer attribute is the problem.